# photo mosaics in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any jquery plugin or a javascript library to produce photo mosaics, ie creating an image made up of smaller images ? (cf: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_mosaic)

Comment: Wouldn't this be more suitable as a server side job?

Comment: Maybe the jQuery plugin called "PhotoMosaic" might be worth looking at. http://jquerylist.com/photos_images_galleries/photo-mosaic.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a JS solution for creating photomosaic using average colors of a tile.

```
 function photomosaic(image) {
      // Dimensions of each tile
      var tileWidth = TILE_WIDTH;
      var tileHeight = TILE_HEIGHT;

      //creating the canvas for photomosaic
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      canvas.height = image.height;
      canvas.width = image.width;

      var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
      var pixels = imageData.data;

      // Number of mosaic tiles
      var numTileRows = image.width / tileWidth;
      var numTileCols = image.height / tileHeight;


      //canvas copy of image
      var imageCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var imageCanvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
      imageCanvas.height = image.height;
      imageCanvas.width = image.width;
      imageCanvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0);


      //function for finding the average color
      function averageColor(row, column) {
          var blockSize = 1, // we can set how many pixels to skip

              data, width, height,
              i = -4,
              length,
              rgb = {
                  r: 0,
                  g: 0,
                  b: 0
              },
              count = 0;          

          try {
              data = imageCanvasContext.getImageData(column * TILE_WIDTH, row * TILE_HEIGHT, TILE_HEIGHT, TILE_WIDTH);
          } catch (e) {
              alert('Not happening this time!');
              return rgb;
          }

          length = data.data.length;

          while ((i += blockSize * 4) < length) {
              ++count;
              rgb.r += data.data[i];
              rgb.g += data.data[i + 1];
              rgb.b += data.data[i + 2];
          }

          // ~~ used to floor values
          rgb.r = ~~(rgb.r / count);
          rgb.g = ~~(rgb.g / count);
          rgb.b = ~~(rgb.b / count);

          return rgb;

      }

      // Loop through each tile
      for (var r = 0; r < numTileRows; r++) {
          for (var c = 0; c < numTileCols; c++) {
              // Set the pixel values for each tile
              var rgb = averageColor(r, c)
              var red = rgb.r;
              var green = rgb.g;
              var blue = rgb.b;

              // Loop through each tile pixel
              for (var tr = 0; tr < tileHeight; tr++) {
                  for (var tc = 0; tc < tileWidth; tc++) {

                      // Calculate the true position of the tile pixel
                      var trueRow = (r * tileHeight) + tr;
                      var trueCol = (c * tileWidth) + tc;

                      // Calculate the position of the current pixel in the array
                      var pos = (trueRow * (imageData.width * 4)) + (trueCol * 4);

                      // Assign the colour to each pixel
                      pixels[pos + 0] = red;
                      pixels[pos + 1] = green;
                      pixels[pos + 2] = blue;
                      pixels[pos + 3] = 255;
                  };
              };
          };
      };

      // Draw image data to the canvas
      context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
      return canvas;
  }

  function create() {
      var image = document.getElementById('image');
      var canvas = photomosaic(image);
      document.getElementById("output").appendChild(canvas);
  };
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/gurinderiitr/sx735L5n/